# Chrome browser keeps losing home page setting

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser

whenever I close down my laptop (Windows 7) and restart chrome comes up with a single default tab despite the fact that I frequently set my home pages to the ones I want to see.

How do I get my settings to "stick"?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I would scan for malware just as a precaution against browser hijackers.

Comment: I think it's setup for the spammy answer it's got.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the shortcut you are using doesn't have any extra startup parameters set. Sometimes if you've been subjected to malware the malicious code will modify your shortcut to always go directly to a specific website, or possibly in your case load a specific profile. Your antivirus may have removed it but the shortcut's parameters remain. Check the properties of the shortcut, in the 'target' section, look for any extra switches at the end of the file path.

Have a look to see if you have *--profile-directory="Default"*. If it is then maybe the profile is corrupted.

In which case you should create a new one:

1. Exit Google Chrome completely.
2. Enter the keyboard shortcut Windows key  +E to open Windows Explorer.
3. In the Windows Explorer window that appears enter the following in the address bar.

   - Windows Vista/ Windows 7/ Windows 8: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
4. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

If you wish, you can transfer information from your old user profile to your new one. However, this action is not recommended, since a part of your old profile may be corrupt. With that in mind, to transfer your old bookmarks, copy the "Bookmarks.bak" file from the "Backup default" folder to your new "Default" folder. Once moved, rename the file from "Bookmarks.bak" to "Bookmarks" to complete the migration. All other browser data will remain in the "Backup default" folder, but you won't be able to transfer it to your new profile.

source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en